# How to make this button/toggle/switch?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make this toggle,

[image: Screenshot of what I want to make]

Any idea's how to go about this?

It looks like one shape, but with a cube and subdivision surface I'm not quite getting there.

[image]

Any idea's? :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Like this? https://snipboard.io/WVa9ID.jpg

Comment: Hello and welcome. Like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex8iY.png

Comment: Hi, yes, kind off, how did you make that? But the first screenshot I added is what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the quickest way.

1. Create a `Cylinder` and shape it like a button.
2. Select two facing verts on the top edge ring and press `J`.
3. Repeat step 2 for the other edge.
4. Select the face representing the handle and press `E`.
5. Select the corner edges of the handle and press `S` to scale it down a bit.
6. Select all faces of the handle plus top and bottom edge rings of the 'button' and press `Ctr B` to bevel it. Done.

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! I feel a bit stupid for not realizing this was the way. But thanks for taking the time to add the video/gif.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some step by step pictures.

I used Cylinder,and box, Joined them, adjusted the box scale and tapering. Deleted the top cylinder polygon and the the bottom box polygon. Added a bevel for the box edges. Created a face from selected edges. Added some edges and scaled as needed for a bevel. Also added a few edges withthe Knife tool to help make the transition from box to cylinder smooth. Then added the Subdivision Surface Modifier.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your extended reply. I feel like the way suggested by Hendrik feels a bit easier, but interesting to see this is an option too. Thanks for taking the time to answer this! :)